# Plotly python timedelta64 (10:43:23.123456) not showing up the same on scatter plot graph

Tags: plotly, scatter-plot, timedelta, plotly-python

```
df_exec['exctn_tim']

0   10:40:01.169646
1   10:40:01.169709

Name: exctn_tim, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I want to plot the graph using exctn_tim as x-axis, but when I do this in Plotly Scatter graph, it automatically changes to something like:
`38.40117T` which is completely not a readable time format and it messes up my whole graph.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems that this is an [open issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/801) in Plotly, and timedelta64 seems to not be a supported format.

[One possible workaround](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/801#issuecomment-317174985) would be to convert this particular column of the dataframe into a format containing date and time: `df_exec['exctn_tim'] = df_exec['exctn_tim'] + pd.to_datetime('1970/01/01')`